# Заменить плохое слово на *** в списке

Tags: python

Дано предложение в котором нужно заменить плохие слова на ***, но у меня заменяется только 1 слово, хотя тут их 2. Можете подправить мой код?

```
txt = 'Fuck you bitch'.lower().split(' ')

bw  = ["fuck", "bitch"]

for j in txt:
    if j in bw:
        temp = [x.replace(j, "***") for x in txt]


res = ' '.join(temp)

print(res)
```

Comment: Переменная temp при каждом проходе создаётся заново и в ней остаётся только самая последняя замена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
txt = 'Fuck you bitch'.lower().split(' ')

bw  = ["fuck", "bitch"]

for j in txt:
    if j in bw:
        txt = [x.replace(j, "***") for x in txt]


res = ' '.join(txt)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через регулярное выражение, в качестве бонус регистр текста не нужно менять (за это отвечает флаг `re.IGNORECASE`):

```
import re

txt = 'Fuck you bitch'

bw = ["fuck", "bitch"]
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(bw), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

txt = pattern.sub('***', txt)
print(txt)
# *** you ***
```

Еще можно сделать так, чтобы количество `*` соответствовало длине замененного слова:

```
txt = pattern.sub(lambda m: '*' * len(m.group()), txt)
print(txt)
# **** you *****
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\b(fuck|bitch)s?', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

result = re.sub(regex, '***', 'Fuck you bitch')

print(result)
```

В итоге не надо самим заморачиваться по поводу верхнего или нижнего регистра

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю традиционно однострочник. С использованием тернарного `if` и генераторного выражения. А ещё с сохранением исходного регистра слов. И ещё я превратил список недопустимых слов во множество - так проверка на вхождение работает гораздо быстрее в случае если список будет достаточно длинный.

```
txt = 'Fuck you bitch'.split(' ')
bw  = set(["fuck", "bitch"])
res = ' '.join('***' if word.lower() in bw else word for word in txt)
print(res)
```